# pythonの独学の勉強順について

Tags: python

pythonでwebアプリをつくったり、実用レベルまで独学でがんばろうと思います。

Pythonスタートブック
みんなのPython 第3版

はすべてコードも打ち込みました。
ですがまだイマイチ何かを作れる気がしません。

次はどういったものをやったほうがよいのでしょうか？
お願い致します。

Answer (score 3):

何か作りたいものを決めて、挑戦してみてはどうでしょうか？
webアプリをpythonで作りたいなら、djangoフレームワークを学ぶのが良いと思います。

https://www.djangoproject.com/

Comment: Djangoはチュートリアルが充実していて、コンポーネントも揃っていますが、その分大きいので、始めはbottleを使ってみるというのも選択肢として良いと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。djangoを調べてみました。ウェブアプリなどをつくってみたいので参考になりました。ただ日本語の初心者向けの書籍などが見つからず、少し苦戦しています。

Answer (score 0):

まずはやりたいことやるというのが大前提ですが、

勉強する目的はなんなのでしょうか？
つまり、職業としてプログラマーになることなのでしょうか？それとも趣味のプログラミングで他人の目に触れるところにプログラムを発表することなのでしょうか？

少なくとも、趣味でプログラミングをする場合、サーバーサイド方面に進むのはあまりよろしくない気がします。というのは、今はサーバを用意しやすくなったとはいえ、他人に使ってもらうサーバをセットアップするのはプログラミング以外の要素がかなり多く、それに煩わされているという感覚を持つと続かなくなってしまうように思うので。

では何が、というと、アプリケーションのプラグインなんかが手軽に始められてすぐ結果が見えて、フィードバックが受けやすくモチベーション維持につながりやすいようにおもいます。

ではどのアプリケーションがオススメ？ということになるかと思うのですが、最初に言ったとおり自分でやってみたいものをやるのがいいとは思いますが、個人的な興味としては

QGIS
http://qgis.org/ja/site/index.html

とかですかね

Comment: ウェブサイトやウェブアプリを作ってみたいというのが目的です。
QGIS
http://qgis.org/ja/site/index.html
初めて知りました。とてもおもしろそうですね。こういったものもあるのですね。
ありがとうございます。